# In Brainrender is there a way to at labels and stop the brain from load upside down?

Tags: python, 3d, vtk

I am using [brainrender](https://github.com/BrancoLab/BrainRender/blob/master/Examples/using_notebooks.ipynb) to show where I've placed some electrodes. However, whenever I load brainrender my brain always loads upside down:

brainrender[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Is there a way to fix this? Or do I just have to manually flip it every time?

I was also wondering if any one knew of a way to display/add text labels to the 3D image the brainrender makes? I did look at these functions, but as far as I can tell neither one actually places a label on a brain area.

labels: [image: 5]

Comment: Hi @Jackie I suggest to submit an issue at https://github.com/BrancoLab/BrainRender/issues you will probably a quick feedback

Comment: For others, this is a link to this same question on the GitHub page: https://github.com/BrancoLab/BrainRender/issues/70

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I've copied the important parts of how to resolve the issues/questions posted here. All credit for an answer to this question goes to the developer of BrainRender(FedeClaudi on GitHub). I am copying the key information he provide my team in case the following link to the developers answer stops working: https://github.com/BrancoLab/BrainRender/issues/70

The developer of the BrainRender tool updated this tool to version 0.4.0.0 which allows users to permanently add labels to brain areas:

`pip install -U brainrender`

You should also update using:

```
https://github.com/BrancoLab/BrainRender.git
```

Some key things to know about how the labels work:

- Labels appear on the right hemisphere by default
- added `xoffset`, `yoffset` and `zoffset` to manually alter the location of the label
- added a colored sphere to the point on the mesh that corresponds to the label location [optional]

This is how we resolved our brain loading upside down, it turns out this is just an issue that occurs with Jupyter notebook:

```
from vtkplotter import embedWindow

from brainrender.scene import Scene



# Change 1 Disable scene embedding with k3d in vtkplotter

embedWindow(False) 



# Change 2 set jupyter to False when creating the scene

scene = Scene(jupyter=False)



# Populate and render 

scene.add_brain_regions(['MOp', 'MOs', 'VISl', 'VISp', 'RSPagl'], add_labels=True)

scene.add_text('title')

scene.render(camera='top')
```

The developer also warned "to avoid `import vtkplotter as vtk` because there's another package called `vtk`".